# How to check if two pictures "touching" each others?

Tags: graphics, c#-4.0, xna, xna-4.0, image

I'm writing a game in wich the user is having a spaceship and need to "kill" some enemeis that wiil try to kill him back.
I have a "Texture 2d" for the user's spaceship picture,a bullet picture and an enemy picture.
I would like to know,after the user has shoot the bullet to the enemy,how can I check that the bullet has hurts the enemy?
In other words - what function checks that one picture is "covering" (even partial) another one?

Thnx!
:-)

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look into the topic "2D Collision Detection". As you are using XNA the following site should give you a good start:
http://www.progware.org/Blog/post/XNA-2D-Basic-Collision-Detection.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to detect when two non-transparent pixels are overlapping, but to prevent unnecessary calculations, you first check if the bounding box for your ship and the enemy ships is even overlapping (since the pixels won't overlap if the bounding boxes don't).

[Riemers.net](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series2D/Coll_Detection_Overview.php) has a good tutorial. Here's a [good sample project](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/tutorial/collision_2d_perpixel) on per-pixel collision detection from the app hub.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unaware of any pre-existing API functions that do this, but implementing it yourself will be a good exercise.

You should know the x/y coordinates of each of your picture's origins.  You should also know the dimensions of each picture.

You can calculate the bounding box of a picture, and whether there exist any points in common.

Comment: Well,it may be a good idea,but I heard that a function as this exist,and my program would look batter if I'll use it..